# How to enforce a curly braces ONLY object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Hi I'm trying to make a function that only takes in an object that has a key-value pair object put in this specific form only:

`{ key: value }` Where key or value can be anything. as long as it is in curly braces.

I don't want to accept any other value that doesn't have the curly brace format.
Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
// What do I put as the type for "param"?
function func(param: object) {

}

func({ hello: "world" }) // <-- I only want this one to work
func([1,23,4])           // this shouldn't work

class T {}

func(T)                  // This shouldn't work as well
func(new T())            // Neither should this
func(function() {})      // Neither should this
```

What type would I need to put into `params` to only accept an object with the curly braces format?

Comment: `param: Record<string, unknown>` [see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dilshan for the answer:

```js
function func(param: Record<string, unknown>) {
}
```

More info on Record: [Record<Keys, Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

What I was doing wrong here was I was using `Record<string, any>` instead of `unknown` when I was experimenting with `Record`.